# Align icon on the right and center the text in a QPushButton

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, qpushbutton, qicon

I'm trying to align the icon to the right and center the text in a QPushButton, but I'm not satisfied with the result for now. I would also like the icon to be completely to the right of the QPushButton and not centered with the text. Likewise I would like this to work with an icon positioned to the right or left while being able to choose the width of the button. Do you have a solution ? Can you help me ? Here is my code for now:

```
# Les boutons du bas pour passer d'une page à l'autre
bout_pag_charg_enr_phase_1 = QPushButton("Aller directement à la page de maintenance de la Séquence")
bout_pag_charg_enr_phase_1.setFixedWidth(406)
bout_pag_charg_enr_phase_1.setIcon(QIcon('logo_png_apsc'+os.sep+'icone_3_fleches_droite_apsc_256x256.png'))
bout_pag_charg_enr_phase_1.setIconSize(QSize(16, 16))
bout_pag_charg_enr_phase_1.setLayoutDirection(Qt.RightToLeft)
bout_pag_charg_enr_phase_1.setStyleSheet("text-align: center; background-color: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1, stop: 0 #fdfbf7, stop: 1 #6190F2);border-style: solid;border-width: 2px;border-radius: 8px;border-color: #9BB7F0;padding: 3px")
bout_pag_suivante_phase_1 = QPushButton("Page suivante")
bout_pag_suivante_phase_1.setFixedWidth(120)
bout_pag_suivante_phase_1.setIcon(QIcon('logo_png_apsc'+os.sep+'icone_2_fleches_droite_apsc_256x256.png'))
bout_pag_suivante_phase_1.setIconSize(QSize(16, 16))
bout_pag_suivante_phase_1.setLayoutDirection(Qt.RightToLeft)
bout_pag_suivante_phase_1.setStyleSheet("background-color: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1, stop: 0 #fdfbf7, stop: 1 #6190F2);border-style: solid;border-width: 2px;border-radius: 8px;border-color: #9BB7F0;padding: 3px")
```

What I get:

[image]

What I want:

[image]

Comment: You could show a picture of what you get, and what you want to get

Comment: What I get --> http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2018/47/3/1542816908-apsc-1-0-0-21-11-2018-001.png .

Comment: What I want --> http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2018/47/3/1542816987-apsc-1-0-0-21-11-2018-002.png

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A possible solution is to place on top and on the right side a QLabel that shows the icon.

```
import os
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class PushButton(QtWidgets.QPushButton):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PushButton, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setStyleSheet('''background-color: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1, stop: 0 #fdfbf7, stop: 1 #6190F2);
            border-style: solid;border-width: 2px;
            border-radius: 8px;
            border-color: #9BB7F0;padding: 3px;''')

        icon = self.icon()
        icon_size = self.iconSize()
        # remove icon
        self.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon())
        label_icon = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        label_icon.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)
        label_icon.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_TransparentForMouseEvents)
        lay = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)
        lay.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        lay.addWidget(label_icon, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignRight)
        label_icon.setPixmap(icon.pixmap(icon_size))

class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        icon = QtWidgets.QApplication.style().standardIcon(QtWidgets.QStyle.SP_ArrowRight)
        # icon = QtGui.QIcon(os.path.join('logo_png_apsc', 'icone_3_fleches_droite_apsc_256x256.png'))

        bout_pag_charg_enr_phase_1 = PushButton("Aller directement à la page de maintenance de la Séquence",
            icon=icon, iconSize=QtCore.QSize(16, 16))
        bout_pag_charg_enr_phase_1.setFixedWidth(506)

        bout_pag_suivante_phase_1 = PushButton("Page suivante",
            icon=icon, iconSize=QtCore.QSize(16, 16))
        bout_pag_suivante_phase_1.setFixedWidth(140)

        lay = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(bout_pag_charg_enr_phase_1)
        lay.addWidget(bout_pag_suivante_phase_1)        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = MyWindow()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: I just tested and it works. By adapting it a bit your solution is exactly what I was looking for ! Many thanks !